# Cumulative distribution function for discrete distribution on $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, rational-numbers

Consider a function $F : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ with the following $3$ properties:

1. $F$ is monotonically increasing,
2. $F$ is right-continuous and
3. $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x) = 1.$

Such a function $F$ is called a cumulative distribution function. Every $F$ defines a probability distribution $P_F$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ via 
$$ P_F((-\infty,t]) :=F(t) $$
On the other hand, every probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ defines a cumulative distribution function $F_P(t)$ via $$ F_P(t) := P((-\infty,t]).$$
So we can see, that there is a bijection between all probability distributions on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ and all cumulative distribution functions.

Now let $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of all rational numbers. Then we can define a probability measure $P_{\mathbb{Q}}$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ by demanding $P_{\mathbb{Q}}(q_n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $P_{\mathbb{A}} (x) = 0$ if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

My question is now: how can the corresponding cumulative distribution function $F_{P_{\mathbb{Q}}}$ be described? The question is puzzling to me; I cannot possibly imagine, that such a function can be (say) right-continuous.

I am happy to hear any thoughts on this!

Kind regards,
Joker

Comment: You should be able to prove that it is still right-continuous.

Comment: Obviously, in this case, $$F(t)=\sum_n2^{-n}\mathbf 1_{q_n\leqslant t}$$ hence, for every fixed $t$ and every positive $\epsilon$, $$F(t+\epsilon)-F(t)=\sum_n2^{-n}\mathbf 1_{t<q_n\leqslant t+\epsilon}$$ Now, fix $N$ and consider the set $$B_N=\{q_n\mid1\leqslant n\leqslant N\}$$ For $\epsilon$ small enough, $$B_N\cap(t,t+\epsilon]=\varnothing$$ hence $$F(t+\epsilon)-F(t)\leqslant\sum_{n>N}2^{-n}=2^{-N}$$ This shows that $F$ is continuous from the right at $t$.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!